# How to pick up a file from resources folder of maven directory structure in a spring boot application?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, resources

How to pick up a file from resources folder of maven without specifying path? Is there a configuration file from which I can pick up the address?

Answer (score 0):

You can check ResourceUtils class. For example if you want to read a json file:

```
private final static TypeReference<Map<String, String>> typeReference = new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
};
Map<String, String> map = 
mapper.readValue(ResourceUtils.getURL("classpath:some.json").openStream(), typeReference);
```